# How can I dynamically change the text that appears under and app bar button?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I have an app bar button and I would like to change the text that appears under it dynamically through codebehind. I tried changing its Content property, but it changes the icon.

I wasn't able to find the answer on stackoverflow nor through the interwebs...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In code, write the following:

```
AutomationProperties.SetName(myAppBarButton, "New text");
```

If you look at the way the caption works, they are "hijacking" the `AutomationProperties.Name` attached property for this purpose and then binding it inside.

Comment: That is such a hack, can't believe they are doing this.

Comment: It's (fairly) straightforward to write your own class with an attached property and search/replace that class/prop in StandardStyles.xml. I have no idea why they are doing it like that - it's so twisted.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the standardstylesheet.xaml and add a new Key like the ones found there already!

```
<Style x:Key="SkipBackAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="SkipBackAppBarButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Skip Back"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE100;"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: That's not dynamic; that's static ;). And this method doesn't work very well if you want to localize to other languages.